# how can my python code automatically know which row to stop at in Excel

Tags: python, excel, rows, openpyxl

I have an Excel worksheet. The below code is to be applied to every row of data. right now it is specified at 100 rows. The number of rows will change each time I run this code. I have to manually open my script and adjust the number of rows. Is there a way to not have a manual process each time and the relevant number of rows are calculated automatically. I do not have much knowledge in coding. Please help.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Formal Units.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

last_row = 100  
    data_column = 26
    result_column = 10
    
    for i in range(2, last_row):
        if sheet.cell(row=i, column=data_column).value == "R":
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=result_column).value = "Y"
        else:
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=result_column).value = "N"

wb.save('Formal Units.xlsx')
```

Comment: What library are you using to read the files?

Comment: i am using openpyxl

Comment: looks like you can modify last_row like below and try `last_row = sheet.max_row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate rows with `iter_row` to get openpyxl Cell objects or just `values` to get cell values.

In your example:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Formal Units.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
rows_generator = sheet.values
data_column = 26
result_column = 10
headers = next(rows_generator)  # comment if you don't have header row
for (i, row) in enumerate(rows_generator, start=2):  # if you don't have header row start=1
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=result_column).value = 'Y' if row[data_column-1] == 'R' else 'N'  # -1, because list is 0 indexed
wb.save('Formal Units.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
wb.worksheets[0]['h6'] = None

print((wb.worksheets[0].max_row, wb.worksheets[0].max_column))

def find_edges(sheet):
    row = sheet.max_row
    while row > 0:
        cells = sheet[row]
        if all([cell.value is None for cell in cells]):
            row -= 1
        else:
            break
    if row == 0:
        return 0, 0

    column = sheet.max_column
    while column > 0:
        cells = next(sheet.iter_cols(min_col=column, max_col=column, max_row=row))
        if all([cell.value is None for cell in cells]):
            column -= 1
        else:
            break
    return row, column

print(find_edges(wb.worksheets[0]))
```